# Adding "areaServed" to LocalBusiness without diminishing Google Local Pack status

Tags: schema.org, local-seo, google-local-search

Google Local Pack is extremely important to our service locations. Having said that, we would like to take advantage of `areaServed` schema. Example 4 suggests this: https://schema.org/LocalBusiness

If we follow that example, will our Google Local Pack status be diminished at all?

If so, what is the correct way to add `areaServed` to our service based locations?

Here is my JSON-LD. Is this the best way to achieve `areaServed` for a `LocalBusiness`?

```json
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org/",
 "@type": "Service",
 "serviceType": "Roof Installation",
 "provider":
       {
           "@type": "HomeAndConstructionBusiness",
           "@id":"[OfficeSiloHomeURL]",
           "name": "[Name]",
           "address":  
               {
                   "@type": "PostalAddress",
                   "streetAddress": "[Address]",
                   "addressLocality": "[City]",
                   "addressRegion": "[State]",
                   "postalCode": "[Zip]"
               },
           "telePhone": "[Phone]",
           "email":  "[email]",
           "openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 08:00-17:00",
           "geo":  
               {
                   "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                   "latitude": "[lat]",
                   "longitude": "[long]"
               },
           "url": "[Url]",
           "logo": "[Logo]",
           "image": "[Image]",
           "aggregateRating":  
               {
                   "@type": "AggregateRating",
                   "ratingValue": "[Value]",
                   "bestRating": "5",
                   "ratingCount": "[Count]"
               }
       },
 "areaServed":
   {
       "@type": "City",
       "name": ["[City1]", "[City2]", "[City3]", "[City4]", "[City5]", "[City6]"]
   },
 "hasOfferCatalog":
   {
       "@type": "OfferCatalog",
       "name": "Roof Installation Service",
       "itemListElement":
           [          
               {
                   "@type": "OfferCatalog",
                   "name": "One-time services",
                   "itemListElement":
                       [
                           {
                               "@type": "Offer",
                               "itemOffered":
                                   {
                                       "@type": "Service",
                                       "name": "Tile Roof Installation"
                                   }
                           },
                           {
                               "@type": "Offer",
                               "itemOffered":
                                   {
                                       "@type": "Service",
                                       "name": "Metal Roof Installation"
                                   }
                           },         
                           {
                               "@type": "Offer",
                               "itemOffered":
                                   {
                                       "@type": "Service",
                                       "name": "Shingle Roof Installation"
                                   }
                           }       
                      ]
               }
           ]
   },
"potentialAction":
   {
       "@type":"ReserveAction",
       "target":
           {
               "@type":"EntryPoint",
               "urlTemplate": "[AppointmentFormURL]",
               "inLanguage":"en-US",
               "actionPlatform":
                   [
                       "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform",
                       "http://schema.org/IOSPlatform",
                       "http://schema.org/AndroidPlatform"
                   ]
           },
       "result":
               {
                   "@type":"Reservation",
                   "name":"Book an Appointment"
               }
           }
   }       
}
```

Comment: This is a great question. I was wondering the same thing since I do select states and am concerned about using /localBusiness in schema. Wonder if for your situation if county is available instead of city?